# Why `std::string`'s assignment operator take `char` by value and not `const` reference?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, implicit-conversion, std

Accidentally I came across below situation:

```
int i = 1000;
string s;
s = i; // ok, but value of `s` is not 1000!
```

This situation was created due to below operator from `string` standard library:

```
string& string::operator=(_CharT __c) 
{ 
  this->assign(1, __c); 
  return *this;
}
```

Now, this is creating an unwanted bad effect where accidentally we may end up assigning an integer to a `string` with erroneous value!
For example, in my case `i` was earlier a `string` and then I converted to `int`. The code still compiled but the program crashed due to its obvious bad effect on overall code.

This situation would be avoided, if it was:

```
string& operator=(const _CharT& c);
```

What is the motivation behind not having above version?

Comment: You might want to rethink your premise: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68856fcbf9f12175

Comment: And another [seen live here](http://ideone.com/Ztd2T6). CNR. A verbatim MCVE would go a long way in demonstrating whatever it is you seem to be seeing, because we're not.

Comment: @chris, thanks for pointing out. I have now edited my question.

Comment: This operator overload is evil and shouldn't exist at all. But that's the hindsight speaking...

Comment: Even if the operator were defined as you suggest, the [situation would be the same](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b3c7ef7c46dfb4b). The problem is the implicit conversion rules.

Comment: @Mankarse, Interesting. In such case, the only way is to make define `string& operator=(const int&)` and make it `private`. However still the question remains: "Why does C++ allow `int` to `const char&` conversion?" I always thought it is not allowed! My bad.

Comment: @iammilind, C++ allows `int` to `char` conversion, so your suggested overload would just create that temporary then bind a reference to it. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2372 for a better "fix", which has its own problems and is probably not going to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the motivation behind not having above version?

It doesn't solve the problem (it doesn't work how you think it works) and it would be slower.

Passing a `char` (or even `wchar_t` or `char32_t`) by value is faster on most architectures than creating a reference and then accessing through the reference, because it requires passing a pointer-sized object (which is usually bigger than a `char` and on 64-bit systems is probably also bigger than `wchar_t`) and then doing an indirection through a pointer.

So it would not fix the problem you are trying to fix it would just make code slower. Double bad.

C++ allows int to char conversion, so your suggested overload would just create that temporary then bind a reference to it. See http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2372 for a better "fix", which has its own problems and is probably not going to happen.